# Are methods of mongoose private?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I started working on boiler plate code of mean.io and want to add resetpassword controller which would update salt, hashed password of it.

I defined(mean.io) a method called make salt in Userschema as follows

```
UserSchema.methods = {
    /**
     * Make salt
     *
     * @return {String}
     * @api public
     */
    makeSalt: function() {
        return crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('base64');
    };
};
```

When I try to access User.makeSalt in user controller. It couldn't find makesalt method. Can't I access model methods from its controller?

Comment: No, of course. Make sure it is an instance and not the object directly (`new User().makeSalt` rather than `User.makeSalt()`);

Comment: You may want `UserSchema.statics.makeSalt = function() { };`, then `User.makeSalt()` would work.

Comment: new User().makeSalt() worked.